# jQuery Mobile inject external page using URL with jquery

Tags: jquery-mobile, dynamic, view

Im try to inject in my index some other pages like "profile.html" or "contact.html". For some pages i want to keep in memory and user can go back, and some others dont. This pages i want to load in the main index page <\div>. 
Can anyone give some code example? 
[Something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgEtX.jpg)

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're asking.  How complex or how much content is on your other pages?  It might be better to just put all your pages into one HTML file and load it all at once and change pages within your index.html file.

If you have some pages that have a lot of images or content that takes time to load, you'd probably  want to use the changePage() function [jQuery Mobile changePage()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jquery.mobile.changepage/)

Comment: Well. I want to load some html files with some html code in to <div id="pages"></div> (this is in index.html). Not to load all the page. just load some code in to index.

Comment: Forget it: You have to load the page via ajax, have to extract the content by using regex and insert it in your page. That takes a lot of time, the user experience will go to zero and to extract the content is complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe as your problem, is exactly the default way how jquery-mobile loads "pages" into the DOM.

Lets build an example:

#### index.html

- header with all referencesto jquery, jquery-mobile etc.
- div with data-role="page" > #index
- div with data-role-"page" > #page1

#### page2.html

- div with data-role="page" > #page2

#### page3.html

- header with all references to jQuery, jquery-mobile etc.
- div with data-role="page" > #page3

---

**What happen when I link from x to y ?**

1. open index.html

   - the fist div with the data-role="page" is displayed
   - in this case #index
   - Pages inside of the DOM (#index, #page1)
2. Link from index.html(#index) to #page1

   - nothing is loaded
   - the page #page1 is shown
   - Pages inside of the DOM (#index, #page1)
3. Link from index.html to page2.html

   - the first div with the data-role="page" from page2.html is loaded to the DOM
   - Pages inside of the DOM (#index, #page1, #page2)
   - if you reload the page, you will see a unstyled html page, because page2.html has no js or css file in the head
   - you can link to #index, #page1 and #page2 because all of them are inside of the DOM
4. Link to page3.html with data-ajax="false"

   - The whole page3.html is loaded.
   - Pages inside of the DOM (#page3)
   - a can still link to page2.html
   - you can also link to the first page of index.html, but not the second page.

You can not load more then the first page of a multipage .html file with ajax. To load a multipage, you always have to load the .html file without ajax (data-ajax="false")

**Code index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title></title>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery Mobile -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Index -->
  <div data-role="page" id="index" data-title="index.html">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>Index.html(#index)</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /Header -->

    <!-- Content -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-state-persist ui-btn-active">Index.html</a>
      <a href="#page1" class="ui-btn">Page 1 (intern)</a>
      <a href="page2.html" class="ui-btn">Page 2 (seperate .html file)</a>
      <a href="page3.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn">Page 3 (seperate .html file - no-ajax)</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /Content -->


  </div>
  <!-- /Index -->

  <!-- page1 -->
  <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-title="index.html#page1">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>Index.html#page1</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /Header -->

    <!-- Content -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <a href="#index" class="ui-btn ">Index.html</a>
      <a href="#page1" class="ui-btn ui-state-persist ui-btn-active">Page 1 (intern)</a>
      <a href="page2.html" class="ui-btn">Page 2 (seperate .html file)</a>
      <a href="page3.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn">Page 3 (seperate .html file - no-ajax)</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /Content -->


  </div>
  <!-- /page1 -->


</body>

</html>
```

**Code of page2.html**

```html
<script>
  alert("hello from Page 2");
</script>




<!-- page2 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-title="page2.html">
  <!-- Header -->
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>page2.html</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- /Header -->

  <!-- Content -->
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#index" class="ui-btn ">Index.html</a>
    <a href="#page1" class="ui-btn">Page 1 (inside index.html)</a>
    <a href="page2.html" class="ui-btn ui-state-persist ui-btn-active">Page 2 (seperate .html file - ajax)</a>
    <a href="page3.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn">Page 3 (seperate .html file - no-ajax)</a>
  </div>
  <!-- /Content -->

</div>
<!-- /page2 -->
```

**Code of page3.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title></title>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery Mobile -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    alert("hello from Page 3");
  </script>


</head>

<body>

  <!-- page2 -->
  <div data-role="page" id="page3" data-title="page3.html">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>page3.html</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /Header -->

    <!-- Content -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <a href="index.html" class="ui-btn ">Index.html (First page of a Multipage)</a>
      <a href="index.html#page1" class="ui-btn">Page 1 ((Second page of a Multipage))</a>
      <a href="page2.html" class="ui-btn">Page 2 (seperate .html file - ajax)</a>
      <a href="page2.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-state-persist ui-btn-active">Page 3 (seperate .html file - no-ajax)</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /Content -->

  </div>
  <!-- /page2 -->
</body>

</html>
```